# SSIS project params file "required" selection

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm a bit confused on the documentation for SSIS when it comes to paramter files, so I'm hoping you all can clear it up for me.

I'm working in SSIS.  I have a project.params file that has variables that are used in SSIS.  I'm confused on the "Required" selection box.

according to documentation:

The required selection box says

> Requires that a value, other than the design default, is specified before the package can execute.

What happens when it says "TRUE"?  does this mean EVERY package in the SSIS project requires re-setting the variable's value after deployment?

Does "FALSE" mean that the value I put in while in SSDT will go in?  or will it be blank? and I still need to set it after deployment?

How does this work?
Thanks!

Comment: It means that the value can't ever be blank. Project variables are set in the SSIS Catelog as well, so if you make it as required then the parameter must be configured in Catelog before any packages in the project can be run.

Comment: Thanks.  If i set the values in ssdt does it propogate?

Comment: No, if you set values in SSDT and make it as required, you must set it in SSIS Catelog again, but if you set it as false, SSDT will bring it's values to SSIS catelog. u can try to deploy it.